# JComponents changing positions for a frame if swing calls validate() in a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I have a JPanel where I have components which are moveable.

My problem is that if I use a action in the panel the locations of components in the whole panel are changing theire position to top mid for just a frame than changing back theire positions. I debugged it and know that its coming from validate(). If I use validate() manually it happens without actions, too.

So here is the code for the components that are used in the panel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.DataFactory;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.designtime.DataSourcePlugin;

import com.inform_ac.utils.misc.gui.resizer.ComponentResizer;



/**
 * AButton is a JAVA-Swing component with integrated functional buttons.
 */
public class AButton extends JPanel {

/**
 * SerialVersionUID: 111111111L
 */
protected static final long serialVersionUID = 111111111L;

/**
 * Standard font for displaying text.
 */
protected Font standardFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12);

/**
 * Defining functional JButtons to delete and edit a AButton.
 */
protected ADeleteButton delBtn = new ADeleteButton(this);
protected JButton editBtn = new JButton();
protected String[] editOptionNames = { "Connect", "Deconnect", "Edit" };
protected JPopupMenu popupmenu = new JPopupMenu();
protected Dimension minDimension = new Dimension(120,120);
protected Point location = new Point();

protected DataFactory dataFactory;
protected DataSourcePlugin dataSourcePlugin;


/**
 * Mode: 0 - moving 
     *       1 - connecting
 */
protected int mode = 0;

/**
 * Defining the label for displaying OK or error images.
 */
protected JLabel lblIcon = new JLabel();

protected final JLabel lblInfo1 = new JLabel();
protected final JLabel lblInfo2 = new JLabel();
protected final JLabel lblInfo3 = new JLabel();

public final JButton connectBtn_right = new JButton();
public final JButton connectBtn_left = new JButton();

protected AButton parent;
protected ArrayList<AButton> children = new ArrayList<AButton>();

/**
 * Identifier
 */
protected int id = 0;

/**
 * Constructor with given start coordinates.
 * 
 * @param X
 *            - coordinate
 * @param Y
 *            - coordinate
 */
public AButton(int X, int Y, int index) {
    this.id = index;
    location = new Point(X,Y);
    setBounds(location.x, location.y, minDimension.width, minDimension.height);
    init();

}

/**
 * Private method to initialize main components.
 */
private void init() {
    initPnl();
    initBtns();
    setVisible(true);
    setFocusable(true);
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize the main panel.
 */
private void initPnl() {
    setBackground(UIManager.getColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground"));
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    setPreferredSize(minDimension);
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("CheckBox.border"));
    setFont(standardFont);
    setLayout(null);
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize functional {@linkplain JButton}.
 */
private void initBtns() {
    initEditBtn();
    initDelBtn();
    initIconPnl();
    initConnectorBtns();
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize the delete button. Method have to refresh
 * the size of this AButton to set the button on the top right corner of
 * this AButton.
 */
private void initDelBtn() {
    delBtn.setBounds(getWidth() - 18 - 2, 2, 18, 18);
    delBtn.setFont(standardFont);
    delBtn.setBackground(null);
    delBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    delBtn.setBorder(null);
    delBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    delBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    delBtn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(12, 12));
    delBtn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    delBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(AButton.class
            .getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/close.gif")));
    add(delBtn);
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize the edit button.
 */
private void initEditBtn() {
    initPopupmenu();
    initMouseListener();
    editBtn.setBounds(2,2,21,21);
    editBtn.setFont(standardFont);
    editBtn.setBorder(null);
    editBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    editBtn.setBackground(UIManager
            .getColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleGradient"));
    editBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    editBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    editBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(21, 21));
    editBtn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(18, 18));
    editBtn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
    editBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\akaradag\\Pictures\\JavaIcon\\icon_bearbeiten.gif"));
add(editBtn);
}

protected void initPopupmenu(){
    for(int i = 0; i < editOptionNames.length; i++) {
        popupmenu.add(new AbstractAction(editOptionNames[i]) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5550466652812249477L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Connect")) {
                    if (mode == 1) {
                        mode = 0;
                        showConnectors();
                    } else {
                        mode = 1;
                        showConnectors();
                    }
                } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Deconnect")) {
                    resetConnections();
                }
                else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Edit")) {

                }
            }

        });
    }
}


protected void initMouseListener()
{
    editBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            popupmenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Private method to display or not display the connector buttons
 */
public void showConnectors() {
    boolean connect = false;
    if (mode == 1) {
        connect = true;
    }
    connectBtn_left.setVisible(connect);
    connectBtn_right.setVisible(connect);
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize the connector buttons
 */
private void initConnectorBtns() {
    connectBtn_right.setCursor(Cursor
            .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    connectBtn_right.setVisible(false);
    connectBtn_right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
    connectBtn_right.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(12, 12));
    connectBtn_right.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
    connectBtn_right.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    connectBtn_right.setBorderPainted(false);
    connectBtn_right.setBorder(null);
    connectBtn_right.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    connectBtn_right
            .setBounds(getWidth() - 16, getHeight() / 2 - 5, 15, 15);
    add(connectBtn_right);
    connectBtn_left.setCursor(Cursor
            .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    connectBtn_left.setVisible(false);
    connectBtn_left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
    connectBtn_left.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(12, 12));
    connectBtn_left.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
    connectBtn_left.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    connectBtn_left.setBorderPainted(false);
    connectBtn_left.setBorder(null);
    connectBtn_left.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    connectBtn_left.setBounds(2, getHeight() / 2 - 5, 15, 15);
    add(connectBtn_left);
}

/**
 * Private method to initialize the {@linkplain JLabel} for displaying
 * informations.
 */
private void initIconPnl() {
    lblIcon.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblIcon.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblIcon.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(AButton.class
            .getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/error.png")));
    lblIcon.setBorder(null);
    lblIcon.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));

    lblIcon.setBounds(getWidth() / 4, 3, getWidth() / 2,
            getHeight() / 4 + 2);
    lblIcon.setLayout(null);
    add(lblIcon);

    lblInfo1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, getHeight() / 10));
    lblInfo1.setForeground(SystemColor.desktop);
    lblInfo1.setBounds(22, getHeight() / 2 - 5, getWidth() - 42,
            getHeight() / 8);
    add(lblInfo1);

    lblInfo2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, getHeight() / 10));
    lblInfo2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblInfo2.setBounds(10, getHeight() / 2 - 5 + getHeight() / 8 + 5,
            getWidth() - 20, getHeight() / 8);
    add(lblInfo2);

    lblInfo3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, getHeight() / 10));
    lblInfo3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblInfo3.setBounds(10, getHeight() / 2 - 5 + 2 * (getHeight() / 8 + 5),
            getWidth() - 20, getHeight() / 8);
    add(lblInfo3);
}

public String getLblInfo(int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
        return lblInfo1.getText();
    } else if (index == 2) {
        return lblInfo2.getText();
    } else {
        return lblInfo3.getText();
    }
}

public void setLblInfo(String text, int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
        lblInfo1.setText(text);
    } else if (index == 2) {
        lblInfo2.setText(text);
    } else {
        lblInfo3.setText(text);
    }
}

public Point getLocation() {
    return new Point(getX(), getY());
}

public Point getInputLocation() {
    return connectBtn_left.getLocation();
}

/**
 * Methode um die Location des Objektes zu ändern und dies auch zu repainten. 
 * Dient dazu damit der Fehler das wenn ein Objekt gelöscht wird die restlichen in die Mitte
 * wandern.
 */
public void setLocation(Point p){
    location = p;
}

public Point getOutputLocation() {
    return connectBtn_right.getLocation();
}

public int getMode() {
    return mode;
}

public void setMode(int mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
    showConnectors();
}

public JButton getDelBtn() {
    return delBtn;
}

public int getIndex() {
    return id;
}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.id = index;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setLocation(location.x, location.y);
    if (lblInfo1.getText().equals("Join")) {
        if (children.size() == 2) {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    "C:\\Users\\akaradag\\Pictures\\JavaIcon\\ok-icon.png"));
        } else if (children.size() > 2) {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    AButton.class
                            .getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/warning.png")));
        } else {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    AButton.class
                            .getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/error.png")));
        }
    } else if (lblInfo1.getText().equals("JDBC")
            || lblInfo1.getText().equals("File")) {
        if (parent != null) {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    "C:\\Users\\akaradag\\Pictures\\JavaIcon\\ok-icon.png"));
        } else {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    AButton.class
                            .getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/error.png")));
        }
    }
}

public void setOutput(AButton out) {
    parent = out;
}

public AButton getOutput() {
    return parent;
}

public void addInput(AButton input) {
    if (!contains(input)) {
        this.children.add(input);
    }
}

private boolean contains(AButton in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) {
        if (this.children.get(i).getIndex() == in.getIndex()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public ArrayList<AButton> getInput() {
    return this.children;
}

public void removeFromInput(AButton remove) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) {
        if (this.children.get(i) != null) {
            if (this.children.get(i).getIndex() == remove.getIndex()) {
                this.children.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void resetConnections() {
    if (parent != null) {
        ArrayList<AButton> in = parent.getInput();
        for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
            if (in.get(i).getIndex() == id) {
                in.remove(i);
            }
        }
        parent = null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) {
        this.children.get(i).setOutput(null);
        this.children.get(i).repaint();
    }
    this.children = new ArrayList<AButton>();

//      if(connectionsDeletedNotify != null)
//          connectionsDeletedNotify.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, "Deconnect"));
}

/**
 * Setter for the DataFactory
 * @param df
 */
public void setDataFactory(DataFactory df)
{
    this.dataFactory = df;
}

/**
 * Getter for the DataFactory
 * @return
 */
public DataFactory getDataFactory()
{
    return this.dataFactory;
}

public DataSourcePlugin getDataSourcePlugin() {
    return dataSourcePlugin;
}

public void setDataSourcePlugin(DataSourcePlugin dataSourcePlugin) {
    this.dataSourcePlugin = dataSourcePlugin;
}
}
```

Here is the code of the main panel

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

import org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.settings.WorkspaceSettings;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.DataFactory;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.MasterReport;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.designtime.DataSourcePlugin;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.designtime.DefaultDataFactoryChangeRecorder;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.metadata.DataFactoryMetaData;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.metadata.DataFactoryRegistry;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.inform_ac.reporting.datasource.dataintegrator.frontend.DataintegratorDesignTimeContext;
import com.inform_ac.reporting.datasource.dataintegrator.frontend.component.AButton;
import com.inform_ac.reporting.datasource.dataintegrator.frontend.component.AConfirmDialog;
import com.inform_ac.reporting.datasource.dataintegrator.frontend.component.ADeleteButton;

public class DataintegratorMainPanel extends JPanel {


DataintegratorDesignTimeContext context;
JPopupMenu popmen = new JPopupMenu();

JMenuItem menu1 = new JMenuItem("Add new Datasource:");
JMenuItem menu2 = new JMenuItem("Join");

Dimension dim = new Dimension();
Point holdingPoint , point1, point2;;

/**
 * ArrayList für die visuellen Datasources
 */
ArrayList<AButton> abuttonList = new ArrayList<AButton>();

/**
 * Nummerierungen der abuttons
 */
int index = 0;

/**
 * The <code>Logger</code> of this instance
 */
protected final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataintegratorQueryPanel.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4705352682546516889L;

public DataintegratorMainPanel() {
    initPopupMenu();
    initMouseListener();
}

protected void initMouseListener()
{
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                popmen.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Überschrift bei Rechtsklick
 * @param header
 * @return JComponent
 */
protected JComponent createHeader(String header) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(header);
    label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD,14));
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    return label;
}

protected void giveMouseListenerTo(AButton button) {        
    button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override 
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mouseDragged(me);
            AButton tmp = (AButton) me.getSource();

            //Mode Moving
            if(tmp.getMode()==0){

            Point point = getMousePosition();

            //Über den Rand raus
            if(point != null) {
                point.x = point.x - holdingPoint.x;
                point.y = point.y - holdingPoint.y;

                if(point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0) {
                    tmp.setLocation(point);
                }
                //LOGGER.info(""+point);
            }
            }
            else if (tmp.getMode()==1) {
                point2 = getMousePosition();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });


    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mousePressed(me);

            AButton tmp = (AButton) me.getSource();
            if (tmp.getMode() == 0) {
                holdingPoint = tmp.getMousePosition();
            }

            else if (tmp.getMode() == 1) {
                Point tmp_point = tmp.getLocation();

                point1 = new Point(tmp.connectBtn_right.getLocation().x+tmp_point.x,tmp.connectBtn_right.getLocation().y+tmp_point.y);
                LOGGER.info("point1: "+point1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mouseReleased(me);
            try {
                AButton destination = (AButton) getComponentAt(getMousePosition());
                AButton source = (AButton) me.getSource();
                if (destination != null && source.getMode() == 1) {

                    // Hier muss der Baum verkettet werden
                    if (destination != source) {
                        destination.addInput(source);

                        if (source.getOutput() == null) {
                            source.setOutput(destination);
                        } else {
                            AButton tmp = source.getOutput();
                            tmp.removeFromInput(source);
                            source.setOutput(destination);
                        }
                        source.setMode(0);
                        destination.setMode(0);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                point2 = null;
            }
            point1 = null;
            point2 = null;
            repaint();
        }
    });
    repaint();
}

protected void initPopupMenu() {
    popmen.add(createHeader("Neue Datasource"));
    popmen.addSeparator();

     context = new DataintegratorDesignTimeContext(new MasterReport());

    final DataFactoryMetaData[] datas = DataFactoryRegistry.getInstance()
            .getAll();

    for (final DataFactoryMetaData data : datas) {

        // Some of the DataFactories are not needed
        if (data.isHidden()) {
            continue;
        } else if (!WorkspaceSettings.getInstance().isShowExpertItems()
                && data.isExpert()) {
            continue;
        } else if (!WorkspaceSettings.getInstance().isShowDeprecatedItems()
                && data.isDeprecated()) {
            continue;
        } else if (!WorkspaceSettings.getInstance()
                .isExperimentalFeaturesVisible() && data.isExperimental()) {
            continue;
        } else if (!data.isEditorAvailable()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (data.getDisplayName(getLocale()).equals("Dataintegrator")) {
            continue;
        }

        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction(
                data.getDisplayName(getLocale())) {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7700562297221703939L;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        Point mousePos = getMousePosition();
                        final AButton tmp = new AButton(mousePos.x,mousePos.y,index++);

                        // Action listener hier und nicht in die for schleife
                        tmp.getDelBtn().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                ADeleteButton tmp_1 = (ADeleteButton) arg0
                                        .getSource();
                                AButton source = tmp_1.getAbutton();
                                AConfirmDialog dialog = new AConfirmDialog();

                                int opt = dialog.getState();
                                if (opt == 1) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < abuttonList.size(); i++) {
                                        if (source.getIndex() != abuttonList.get(i)
                                                .getIndex()) {

                                            if (abuttonList.get(i).getOutput() != null
                                                    && abuttonList.get(i).getOutput()
                                                            .getIndex() == source
                                                            .getIndex()) {
                                                abuttonList.get(i).setOutput(null);
                                            }
                                            abuttonList.get(i).removeFromInput(source);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // seperat erst die referenzen löschen dann das
                                    // objekt aus der liste
                                    for (int i = 0; i < abuttonList.size(); i++) {
                                        if (source.getIndex() == abuttonList.get(i)
                                                .getIndex()) {
                                            abuttonList.remove(i);
                                            source.setVisible(false);
                                            source.setEnabled(false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        LOGGER.info("--> data: " + data);
                        final DataSourcePlugin editor = data.createEditor();
                        LOGGER.info("--> editor: " + editor);
                        final DefaultDataFactoryChangeRecorder recorder = new DefaultDataFactoryChangeRecorder();

                        final DataFactory dataFactory = editor.performEdit(context,
                                null, null, recorder);
                        LOGGER.info("--> datafactory: " + dataFactory);

                        // Falls die Datafactory initialisiert werden konnte
                        if (dataFactory != null) {
                            tmp.setDataSourcePlugin(editor);
                            tmp.setDataFactory(dataFactory);

                            add(tmp);

                            //LOGGER.info("New datafact"+mousePos);

                            abuttonList.add(tmp);

                            //Moving listener
                            giveMouseListenerTo(tmp);
                            validate();
                        }


                    }
        });
        popmen.add(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));


        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Line2D tmp_line;
        for (int i = 0; i < abuttonList.size(); i++) {
            if (abuttonList.get(i).getOutput() != null) {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));
                int x1 = abuttonList.get(i).getLocation().x
                        + abuttonList.get(i).connectBtn_right.getLocation().x;
                int y1 = abuttonList.get(i).getLocation().y
                        + abuttonList.get(i).connectBtn_right.getLocation().y;
                int x2 = abuttonList.get(i).getOutput().getLocation().x
                        + abuttonList.get(i).getOutput().connectBtn_left
                                .getLocation().x - 4;
                int y2 = abuttonList.get(i).getOutput().getLocation().y
                        + abuttonList.get(i).getOutput().connectBtn_left
                                .getLocation().y;

                tmp_line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                double m = (y2 - y1) / (double) (x2 - x1);
                //logger.info("m: "+m);

                int vz = x2-x1;
                //LOGGER.info("vz: "+vz);

                if(vz<0)
                {
                    vz = 20;
                }
                else if (vz>0){
                    vz = -20;
                }

                if(m<4 && m>-4) {

                    Point p = new Point(x2 -20, (int) (y1 + m * (x2 - x1 - 20)));
                    //logger.info(p.toString());

                    Line2D tmp2_line = new Line2D.Double(x2, y2, x2 + vz,
                            p.y + 3);
                    //logger.info("x2: "+x2+", y2: "+y2+", p.y:"+p.y);

                    Line2D tmp3_line = new Line2D.Double(x2, y2, x2 + vz,
                            p.y - 3);
                    //logger.info("x2: "+x2+", y2: "+y2+", p.y:"+p.y);

                    g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.draw(tmp2_line);
                    g2d.draw(tmp3_line);
                }
                g2d.draw(tmp_line);

            }
        }
        if (point1 != null && point2 != null) {
            Line2D line2d = new Line2D.Double(point1, point2);
            g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));// set stroke size
            g2d.draw(line2d);
        }
}
}
```

So the error happens if I click on the editBtn und click for example on Connect. It repaints the whole panel and the abuttons in the panel are located in the middle top of the panel vertically for some frames and it goes back to the locations that are saved in the object itselft.

Also I can reproduce the error by using validate().

I dont understand what is the problem here. Why its changing the locations of the components in the main panel after a validation?

And sorry if the code is not SSCCE but I couldn't get it work without the pentaho libraries...

Comment: Actually, just curiosity is forcing me to ask, as to why you using `Absolute Positioning` over using a `Layout Manager` for creating the GUI ? I hope you must have read the first paragraph of [__Absolute Positioning__](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), and well aware of the drawbacks of using the same :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest the use of a layout manager, in any respect it is preferable; it may take you some time at first, but is worthy. For simple use cases, built-in ones, like `BorderLayout`, `GridBagLayout` may suffice. But, for more control, try `MigLayout`: complete, elegant, and precise. (http://www.miglayout.com/)
2. If you ask why, the JavaDoc has it:

> void java.awt.Container.validate()
>
> Validates this container and all of its subcomponents.
>
> Validating a container means laying out its subcomponents. Layout-related changes, such as setting the bounds of a component, or adding a component to the container, invalidate the container automatically. Note that the ancestors of the container may be invalidated also (see Component.invalidate for details.) Therefore, to restore the validity of the hierarchy, the validate() method should be invoked on the top-most invalid container of the hierarchy.
>
> Validating the container may be a quite time-consuming operation. For performance reasons a developer may postpone the validation of the hierarchy till a set of layout-related operations completes, e.g. after adding all the children to the container.
>
> If this Container is not valid, this method invokes the validateTree method and marks this Container as valid. Otherwise, no action is performed.
>
> Overrides: validate() in Component

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed it.

The problem was the default layoutmanager of the JPanel.

After I changed it to `setLayout(null);` the problem disapears.